# Higher Order Function Using Filter for Prime Numbers and Odd Numbers Python

Tags: python

I want to make a Higher Order Function that will take 2 other functions, then a set of numbers, and return a set of numbers that went through that function. Sounds complicated but it's really not, here's my code:

```
#Is_Odd
def is_thodd(n):
    if n % 3 == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Is_Prime
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for f in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % f == 0:
            return False
    return True

def filter(f,x):
    return [f(i) for i in x]
```

Here's what it shoudl do:

```
>>> A = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> filter(is_thodd, A)
[4, 7]
>>> filter(is_prime, A)
[2, 3, 5, 7]
>>> filter(is_prime, [])
[]
```

Here's what it does:

```
>>> A = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> filter(is_thodd, A)
[False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

I can't figure out how to fix it and need help. This is NOT a repeat of another question because it is fixing MY code, not how to do the problem. This is also not homework and is simply a way to better understand higher order functions.

Comment: You are returning booleans into the list, have you tried just returning the value?

Comment: Your filter method should return `[i for i in x if f(i)]`

Comment: What should my return method be? I'm not good with higher order functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to the generator
>   expression `(item for item in iterable if function(item))` if function
>   is not `None` and `(item for item in iterable if item)` if function is
>   `None`. - [built-in `filter` function docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Since `f(i)` returns a boolean, your `filter` function implementation attempt will of course return a list of booleans instead. Instead you need to return the value of `i` only if `f(i)` is `True` like with the built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@rdas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947378/rdas), your filter function should be this:

```py
def filter(predicate, array):
    return [item for item in array if predicate(item)]
```

I know this is just to understand higher order functions, but don't use this practically in a project because the `filter` function is [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).